# What are usecases of MPI_Pack/MPI_Unpack?

Tags: c++, c, concurrency, parallel-processing, mpi

What is the purpose of using MPI_Pack/MPI_Unpack? Is it better than working with mpi structure types or derived types?

Comment: if you use jagged arrays, pack/unpack is easier than one-off derived datatypes.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, Thank you for your reply, is there any other usecases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packing & unpacking is great as a serialization tool: if you can turn an object (in an informal sense) into a sequence of "1 int, 3 chars, 2 doubles, 5 chars, 2 shorts" (or whatever) you can pack this into a "self-documenting message". The receiving side can unpack this with very little knowledge of what is in your message.

The only caveat is that the receiving side may not know the size of the buffer that is incoming, so you may need to do a Probe first.